# How to discover position of points to draw on Canvas?

Tags: canvas, position, curve, gimp

I'm making a map on Canvas and I want to find the position of all the points and control points from my curves so I tried on GIMP but I don't know if its the best way to do it. What I want to know is if you guys know a better way than going point  to point and looking the position on the ruler? [example of what i'm doing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZGpb.png)

Comment: Its not related to code, to draw in canvas you need X, Y from point A and X, Y to point B , what i'm asking is an easier way to know these points without trial and error.

Comment: If is not related to code, then you are posting this question on the wrong place... try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GIMP has an API to extract the points from the "Paths":

```
for stroke in path.strokes:
     points,closed=stroke.points
```

There is a script to export the path points to a CSV, see the [`path-csv` script](http://gimp-path-tools.sourceforge.net/tools.shtml#path-csv)